# Distributed to symbol for frequency distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, notation

How would you write down that some random variable $X$ is distributed to a frequency distribution.

For the normal distribution e.g. I often see sth. like that: $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Is it ok to write $X\sim \mathcal{H}$ with $\mathcal{H}$ as the frequency distribution?

Comment: even $\mathcal{N}$ makes no sense before you define what it is.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören The normal distribution with the two parameters given as I wrote. Is it not correct?

Comment: it is correct but if you just write it as it is and if you dont mention what $\mathcal{N}$ is what $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ is then it is nothing. This means you can name everything how you like but still being consistent with many known common notations. At any case you must name what is means so that it makes sense.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören OK I will do that. But I've never seen a formal description of a random variable distributed to a frequency distribution. That is the reason why I'm asking. Maybe there is a common notation for that.

Comment: I wouldnt see any problem with using $\mathcal{H}$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is the frequency distribution. I have never seen any symbol associated with it. At least it cannot be parameterized by $2$ parameters like in the Gaussian case. We usually say the histogram of .... and it is usually enough because this sentence describes everything about it..